# How to remove the woocommerce_checkout_process action hook in woocommerce if particular project in cart

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I need to remove checkout page field validation if a particular product is in the cart.

Plugin code :

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['developer_name'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please fill in your name.' ), 'error' );
}
```

I need to remove this action hook `my_custom_checkout_field_process` only if the customer added the product_id (19) to the cart. Else there's no need to remove the `add_action`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this below code in your function.php file or in your plugin

```
add_action("init", function () {
    // removing the woocommerce hook
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
            $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
            if($product_id!='19')
            {
        remove_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');
    }
}
});
```

Comment: thanks man it's working

Answer (score 1):

WordPress compiles a list of actions quite early in the process, possibly before the `product_id` is known. So you probably (I don't know where WooCommerce executes this action) cannot execute this action conditionally.

However, what you can do is remove the action completely and define a new action that includes the condition. Also you must make sure this is done before the old action is executed. Like this:

```
add_action ('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wpse333234_change_hook', 1); // early priority

function wpse333234_change_hook () {
  remove_action ('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process'); // remove old hooked function
  add_action ('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wpse333234_new_hook', 10); // define new hooked function with later priority
  }

function wpse333234_new_hook () {
  // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
  if ( ! $_POST['developer_name'] && !$product_id==19)
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Please fill in your name.' ), 'error' );
    }
```

Beware that the latter function will give an error initially, because `$product_id` is not defined in the function. I don't know how this is defined in WooCommerce. You'll need a way to access this (global?) variable in some way.

Comment: @cjbi Thanks for reply. but it's not working..

Comment: Which part is not working?

Comment: It's not removed the validation.